# User Form multi-selection Listbox arrays or entirerow.copy?

Tags: multidimensional-array, listbox, userform, dynamic-arrays

Amateur her so bear with me. I am trying to compile VBA code which runs a userform with list box populated with a 9 column and 100 row table from `worksheet1`. The user selects the only the items in the list box he needs for a report and they are to copied to worksheet 2.
With help from a 6 year old post on this site, I have managed to do this using an array and a public function to select the chosen rows and then output them to `worksheets2`. As follows:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim SelectedItems() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim emptyrow As Integer


wsTarget.Activate
Range("A1").Select

SelectedItems = GetSelectedRisks(RiskList)

emptyrow = 15

For i = LBound(SelectedItems) To UBound(SelectedItems)
    wsTarget.Cells(emptyrow, 2).Value = SelectedItems(i)
    emptyrow = emptyrow + 1
Next

End Sub

Public Function GetSelectedRisks(lBox As MSForms.ListBox) As Variant

Dim tmpArray() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim SelectionCounter As Integer

    SelectionCounter = -1
    For i = 0 To lBox.ListCount - 1
        If lBox.Selected(i) = True Then
            SelectionCounter = SelectionCounter + 1
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray(SelectionCounter)
            tmpArray(SelectionCounter) = lBox.List(i)
        End If
    Next
```

However I can only work out how to do this for the 1st column. I just can't work out how to get the other columns into the array and then back out again.
Should I be using an array or am I making this to complicated i.e. should I just be using loops and if selected, `entirerow.copy` type stuff?